# Web to lead / get source URL

Tags: url, web2lead, hidden-fields

I have the same web to lead code in many web sites.
How could I dynamically set in a custom field on my lead the origin URL, from where the client come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use javascript.  When the page loads, fire a function that sets the custom field value to the window.location.href value